# Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':unimodules-react-native-adapter:debugCompileClasspath',

Tags: react-native, debugging, dependencies

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':unimodules-react-native-adapter:compileDebugAidl'.

  > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':unimodules-react-native-adapter:debugCompileClasspath'.
  >   Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.0.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :unimodules-react-native-adapter
  >   Cannot find a version of 'androidx.core:core' that satisfies the version constraints:

```
  Dependency path 'org.unimodules:unimodules-react-native-adapter:4.0.0' --> 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
           Dependency path 'org.unimodules:unimodules-react-native-adapter:4.0.0' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.61.5' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.1'
           Dependency path 'org.unimodules:unimodules-react-native-adapter:4.0.0' --> 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
           Dependency path 'org.unimodules:unimodules-react-native-adapter:4.0.0' --> 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
           Dependency path 'org.unimodules:unimodules-react-native-adapter:4.0.0' --> 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
           Dependency path 'org.unimodules:unimodules-react-native-adapter:4.0.0' --> 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
           Dependency path 'org.unimodules:unimodules-react-native-adapter:4.0.0' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.61.5' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
           Dependency path 'org.unimodules:unimodules-react-native-adapter:4.0.0' --> 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
           Dependency path 'org.unimodules:unimodules-react-native-adapter:4.0.0' --> 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
           Dependency path 'org.unimodules:unimodules-react-native-adapter:4.0.0' --> 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
           Dependency path 'org.unimodules:unimodules-react-native-adapter:4.0.0' --> 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
           Dependency path 'org.unimodules:unimodules-react-native-adapter:4.0.0' --> 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
           Dependency path 'org.unimodules:unimodules-react-native-adapter:4.0.0' --> 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
           Dependency path 'org.unimodules:unimodules-react-native-adapter:4.0.0' --> 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
           Constraint path 'org.unimodules:unimodules-react-native-adapter:4.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
           Constraint path 'org.unimodules:unimodules-react-native-adapter:4.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
           Constraint path 'org.unimodules:unimodules-react-native-adapter:4.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
```

> Could not resolve androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0.
>        Required by:
>            project :unimodules-react-native-adapter
>   Cannot find a version of 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable' that satisfies the version constraints:

```
 Dependency path 'org.unimodules:unimodules-react-native-adapter:4.0.0' --> 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0'
           Dependency path 'org.unimodules:unimodules-react-native-adapter:4.0.0' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.61.5' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
           Dependency path 'org.unimodules:unimodules-react-native-adapter:4.0.0' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.61.5' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0'
           Constraint path 'org.unimodules:unimodules-react-native-adapter:4.0.0' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
           Constraint path 'org.unimodules:unimodules-react-native-adapter:4.0.0' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
           Constraint path 'org.unimodules:unimodules-react-native-adapter:4.0.0' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
```

BUILD FAILED in 17s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
at runOnAllDevices (E:\A\gamma\reactapp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Answer (score -1):

As a temporary solution:

- open `node_modules/unimodules-react-native-adapter/android/build.gradle`
- search for `compileOnly('com.facebook.react:react-native:+')`
- change it to `implementation('com.facebook.react:react-native:+')`